# Double interval call and it should not be in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I have problem on server side (node.js) with `setInterval`.
I want to check something every day at specific time and I set interval like this:

```
let maintainTime = backFunc.getNextMaintainTime(new Date());
let maintain = setInterval(() => {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    if (currentTime.getTime() > maintainTime.getTime()) {
        maintainTime = backFunc.getNextMaintainTime(maintainTime);
        //do the maintain
    }
}, 360000);
//360000 to check on every hour
```

and here is my `getNextMaintainTime` function:

```js
getNextMaintainTime: (maintainTime) => {
    maintainTime.setDate(maintainTime.getDate() + 1);
    maintainTime.setHours(4);
    maintainTime.setMinutes(0);
    maintainTime.setSeconds(0);
    maintainTime.setMilliseconds(0);

    return maintainTime;
}
```

When I test it out it works perfectly but when I start server on production every time it calls this function 2 times instead of 1 time at 4am, what could cause the problem?

Comment: We will likely have to see a larger code context to see why this might executing more than once.  The most common reason timers appear to fire more than once is that you call the `setInterval()` more than once and you actually end up with two separate timers.

Comment: FYI, there is a more efficient way to do this.  You can call `getNextMaintainTime()` and then use `setTimeout()` to set a timer for that precise time.  When that fires and you get the next maintain time, you again set a new `setTimeout()` for that new time by just subtracting the maintain time from now to get the delta for the `setTimeout()`.  That is how I tell my server to reboot itself every day at 4am and it's been running just fine that way for 5 years.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. Well that's the only code that I have for maintain the app, there is no other places where this appears. I don't know in cPanel when restart the node.js app does it remove old intervals or stack up another one?

Comment: jfriend00 your way sounds good. I will try it out. Can you show me example of how to again setTimout after it fires first time? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think jfriend00 is right. From the code you've posted it looks like the `setInterval` function is called within another function getting a new maintain time. And then you're registering a new interval without clearing the one before. You're not overwriting the interval. The only thing you get back from `setInterval` is the ID of the interval to clear it again. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Comment: Just make a function for setting the next timer.  Call that function to start things and then within the `setTimeout()` callback when you're done with the previous processing and you want to set the next one, call the same function again.

Comment: Same thing with the ID and clearing again applies to `setTimeout`

Comment: @lehnerchristian - You don't have to clear a timerID from within a `setTimeout()` callback since it only ever fires once, once it has fired, it's done.  No need to clear it at that point.  The only time you'd have to clear it is if you're trying to cancel a previously set timer that hasn't yet fired.

Comment: So, the reason I say we need more context is that there's nothing visible in this code that would cause it to run double timers.  Therefore, it seems likely that it has to do with how/when this code is called - somehow getting called more than one.  You can put a simple `console.log()` a few places in this code and check that for yourself as a simple debugging step.

Comment: Yes, @jfriend00, you're right. I didn't mean that they're the same thing, and that they run multiple times. My comment did lack of more context. Thanks for clarifying this :-)

Comment: Thank you for solution. I think with setTimout I will not have this problem. It may be that the problem is caused in cPanel when restarting the server that it did not cleared interval on restarting. I will try with setTimeout now and see what will be. Thank you once again.

Comment: @VeljkoRankovic - If you are truly restarting your server, then it stops the previous process and any previous `setInterval()` actions will indeed stop.

Comment: I do, I know that does not make any sense but that just came up as idea. Since before it worked for few days and then it starts to make double calls at 4am.